# Can't insert record into MS Access through C# oledb

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

I have a table in my MS Access database called "Genres". It has the following columns:

- ID -> AutoNumber
- Index -> Number
- GenreText -> Text

Here is the C# code that I use:

```
public static void AddGenre(string text, int index)
    {
        string query = "INSERT INTO Genres(Index, GenreText) VALUES(@index, @text)";
        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, con);

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@index", index);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text", text);

                con.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException();
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that I always get an exception *"Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement."*

I just can't find the problem. My other functions for manipulating data from the database are working fine.

Comment: Index is a reserved word in MS Access.  Enclose the word in Brackets like so:  Genres([Index], GenreText)

Comment: @Fink, that was the problem. Thank you so much. I have been struggling with this for the last couple of hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Index is a **[reserved keyword](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/286335)** in Access. You need to enclose it in []. Try this:

```
INSERT INTO Genres([Index], GenreText) VALUES(@index, @text)
```